# Is the Bhagavad Gita a distinct chapter of Mahabarata?

Tags: mahabharata

Is Bhagavad Gita specifically named as such in the Mahabarata, or is it just a special name for the part of the Mahabarata given outside the Mahabarata?

And if so by whom?

Answer (score 5):

This is named in Mahabharata itself. Mahabharata contains 100 parvas, one of them is **'Bhagavat-Gita' Parva**.  These 100 parvas again arranged in 18 major parvas. Thus, the **'Bhagavat-Gita'** is a part of **Mahabharata: Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita Parva**.

> The high-souled Vyasa composed these **hundred parvas** of which the above is only an abridgement: having distributed them into **eighteen**, the son of Suta recited them consecutively in the forest of Naimisha as follows:
>   ...
>   Then comes the thrilling story of the installation of Bhishma as commander-in-chief. The next is called the creation of the insular region Jambu; then Bhumi; then the account about the formation of islands. Then comes the **'Bhagavat-gita'**; and then the death of Bhishma. ~[Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01003.htm)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a special name given to a part of the Mahābhārata, outside the Mahābhārata. Although there is a [parva](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/parvan/20203/4) (section) by the name "Bhagavad-gītā" in the 100-parva classification of the Mahābhārata, even within this section, the Bhagavad-gītā is only a part.

> #### Introduction
>
> **How is the Mahabharata classified?**
>
> The core component is the couplet or *shloka*. Several such *shlokas* form a chapter or *[adhyaya](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=adhyAya&lang=sans&action=Search)*. Several *adhyayas* form a *parva*. Most people probably think that the Mahabharata has eighteen *parvas*. This is true, but there is another 100-*parva* classification that is indicated in the text itself. That is, the *adhyayas* can be classified either according to eighteen *parvas* or according to 100 *parvas*. The table (given on pp. xxiii–xxvi), based on the critical edition, should make this clear. As the table shows, the present critical edition only has ninety-eight *parvas* of the 100-*parva* classification, though the 100 *parvas* are named in the text.
>
> [image]
>
> ([Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYKLSZP))

So even if you locate the Bhagavad-gītā parva, you need to have prior knowledge of where the Bhagavad-gītā actually begins and ends. And it begins at [Chapter 23 of Bhīṣma Parva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06023.htm) and ends at [Chapter 40](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06040.htm).

> **Section Sixty-Three**
>
> **Bhagavad Gita Parva**
>
> This parva has 994 shlokas and twenty seven chapters.
>
> Chapter 874 (14): 13 shlokas 
>   Chapter 875 (15): 75 shlokas 
>   Chapter 876 (16): 46 shlokas 
>   Chapter 877 (17): 39 shlokas 
>   Chapter 878 (18): 18 shlokas 
>   Chapter 879 (19): 44 shlokas 
>   Chapter 880 (20): 20 shlokas 
>   Chapter 881 (21): 17 shlokas 
>   Chapter 882 (22): 22 shlokas 
>   **Chapter 883 (23): 47 shlokas**  `[BG STARTS HERE]` 
>   Chapter 884 (24): 72 shlokas 
>   Chapter 885 (25): 43 shlokas 
>   Chapter 886 (26): 42 shlokas 
>   Chapter 887 (27): 29 shlokas 
>   Chapter 888 (28): 47 shlokas 
>   Chapter 889 (29): 30 shlokas 
>   Chapter 890 (30): 28 shlokas 
>   Chapter 891 (31): 34 shlokas 
>   Chapter 892 (32): 42 shlokas 
>   Chapter 893 (33): 55 shlokas 
>   Chapter 894 (34): 20 shlokas 
>   Chapter 895 (35): 34 shlokas 
>   Chapter 896 (36): 27 shlokas 
>   Chapter 897 (37): 20 shlokas 
>   Chapter 898 (38): 24 shlokas 
>   Chapter 899 (39): 28 shlokas 
>   **Chapter 900 (40): 78 shlokas** `[BG ENDS HERE]`
>
> This section is so named because it includes the Song Celestial or the
>   Bhagavad Gita, the teachings of Krishna to Arjuna. The section begins
>   with the dramatic news that Bhishma has been killed. When Sanjaya tells
>   Dhritarashtra this, Dhritarashtra (and the reader) is astounded, wishing
>   to know how this came to be. **After a description of the arrangements for
>   war, the rest of this section is the Bhagavad Gita.**
>
> ([Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYKLSZP))

Answer (score 0):

Bhagwadgeeta is part of Bhishma Parva (one of the 18 parvas or chapters) of Mahabharata. It is not a separate chapter.